# A strange use of c++ keyword of new

Tags: c++, memory, keyword

I met with some codes as below.

```
char *buffer = new char[sizeof(PoolThread) * numThreads];
m_threads = reinterpret_cast<PoolThread*>(buffer);
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
{
    new (buffer)PoolThread(*this);
    buffer += sizeof(PoolThread);
}
```

I guess the `new` here is for initializing the empty memory space pointed to by `m_threads` to a real object (of `PoolThread` class)

I've googled, but only found infos of usage of `new` like this:

```
pointer = new somthing[number];
```

I hope more info of the usage of `new` in my upper code example. And does this usage comes from c++ standard?

Comment: See ["What uses are there for “placement new”?
"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new).

Comment: Yes, I'm asking a duplicate question. I'll pick jack's answer after 7 mins

Comment: Yes, mine is duplicate question with that.

Comment: The real question is: why this code and not `std::vector<PoolThread> m_threads{numThreads, PoolThread{*this}};`. I am thinking that maybe `PoolThread` is not copiable ?

Comment: I think the programmer is avoiding std containers, I've read codes for a whole day, he just writes all data structures by himself. I've also heard that std containers are not samely implemented on different platforms. So, I guess vector is not used because of such concerns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) and it is used when you want to override the normal memory manager of the OS and choose exactly where you want to place an object that you are allocating.

In the code you posted, `buffer` address is used to specify where the element will be allocated (in fact it is modified so that every consecutive allocation follows the address).

Of course, since it frees the memory manager from the duty of memory allocation, it is your own responsibility to provide valid addresses for what you are storing. That's why is it used just when it is really needed.